# spaces in titleMarquee

Tags: javascript, html

I was thinking about this for quite a long time but couldn't figure it out. Just wanted to make spaces after the text when it all goes by in the title.

```
var titleText = document.title

        function titleMarquee()
        {
            titleText = titleText.substring(1, titleText.length) + titleText.substring(0, 1);
            document.title = titleText;
            setTimeout("titleMarquee()", 400);
        }
        </script>
```

Here's the code with classic function.

Tried to figure it out with friends but it wasnt what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Updated after OP's comment. Below code will consume the title one character at a time. It will restore the original title once all characters are gone and restart the marqueue after a while.

```
// first back-up the original title
document.body.dataset['originaltitle'] = document.title;
function titleMarquee()
{
    if (document.title.length === 1) {
        document.title = document.body.dataset['originaltitle'];
        setTimeout("titleMarquee()", 2000);
    }
    else {
        document.title = document.title.substring(1);
        setTimeout("titleMarquee()", 100);
    }
}
titleMarquee();
```

Keep in mind that if you set document.title to any whitespace string, browser automatically shows the url as title.

Comment: Yea, its okay, but I meant that after one loop title will be empty for a while and then it'll make another loop.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly.